# JOLT transformation modify overwrite - replace element value in array

Tags: java, json, jolt, saxparser

I am working on JOLT library to perform a change to the json values.

For key-value items I found a solution using

```json
"operation": "modify-overwrite-beta"
```

But when it comes to edit values inside the arrays I encounter problems.

Let's have for example this JSON:

```json
{
  "parentModule": [
    {
      "childModule": {
        "arrayModule": [
          "KK",
          "VV"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

SPEC I am using

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "parentModule": {
        "*": {
          "childModule": {
            "arrayModule": [
              "TT",
              "RR"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The result I want is that the array is totally override , but currently it is replacing only the first value.

Result expected:

```json
{
 "parentModule": [
    {
      "childModule": {
        "arrayModule": [
          "TT",
          "RR"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to:

1. *completely override the array?*
2. *change values conditionally, for example if **TT** => change to **AB**, else if **RR** than write **BB** ?*

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **shift** transformations along with **`#`** operators in order to represent the fixed element values for the new lists to be created.

For the ***first*** case( if we have **`"arrayModule": ["KK", "VV"]`** for the input ) :

```json
 [
   {
     "operation": "shift",
     "spec": {
       "parentModule": {
         "*": {
           "childModule": {
             "arrayModule": {
               "#TT": "&4[&3].&2.&1[]",
               "#RR": "&4[&3].&2.&1[]"
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
]
```

the **demo1** :

[image]

And for the ***second*** ( if we have **`"arrayModule": ["TT", "RR"]`** for the input ) :

```json
 [
   {
     "operation": "shift",
     "spec": {
       "parentModule": {
         "*": {
           "childModule": {
             "arrayModule": {
               "*": {
                 "TT": { "#AB": "&6[&5].&4.&3" },
                 "RR": { "#BB": "&6[&5].&4.&3" }
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
]
```

the **demo2** :

[image]

while setting proper ampersand levels to reach the desired key names at several levels respectively.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer @Barbaros, can you pls explain what this sintax refers to "&6[&5].&4.&3" to understand it better

Comment: Hi @NadirBertolasi &6 stands for traversing 6 times `{` in order to grab key name `parentModule`, &4 for `childModule`, &3 for `arrayModule`, and `[&5]` represents the indexes under `parentModule` object. You're welcome.