# JOLT Keep structure after array shift

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I'm trying to construct a JOLT transformation such that it will change a parameter value if the paramter name matches in a given array.
Example Input:

```json
{
  "component": {
    "parameters": [
      {
        "parameter": {
          "name": "var_name",
          "value": "val"
        }
      },
      {
        "parameter": {
          "name": "1",
          "value": "2"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "additional": "onemore"
}
```

Desired Output:

```json
{
  "component": {
    "parameters": [
      {
        "parameter": {
          "name": "var_name",
          "value": "new_val"
        }
      },
      {
        "parameter": {
          "name": "1",
          "value": "2"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "additional": "onemore"
}
```

My Current JOLT transform:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "component": {
        "parameters": {
          "*": {
            "parameter": {
              "name": {
                "var_name": {
                  "#new_val": "&6.&5[&4].&3.value"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The problem with my JOLT transform is that it deletes the rest of the Json, whereas I'd like to mantain it unchanged if there's no match

I tried looking for a solution, but the closest I got was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71409263/jolt-transformation-modify-overwrite-replace-element-value-in-array), which allowed me to make the current transform, but I don't understand how to fix it properly.

**EDIT:**

I actually missed part of the input when writing the example, but thanks to @Barbaros Özhan answer I was able to complete my transformation.

For future rference if anybody else needs it my original input had additonal fields like:

```json
{
  "component": {
    "parameters": [
      {
        "option": "true",
        "parameter": {
          "name": "var_name",
          "description": "desc",
          "value": "val"
        }
      },
      {
        "option": "false",
        "parameter": {
          "name": "1",
          "description": "desc",
          "value": "2"
        }
      }
    ],
    "other value": "baz"
  },
  "additional": "onemore"
}
```

And the final transformation I used was slightly tweaked to account for those like so:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "component": {
        "parameters": {
          "*": {
            "parameter": {
              "name": {
                "@": "&5.&4[&3].&2.&1",
                "var_name": {
                  "#new_val": "&6.&5[&4].&3.value"
                },
                "*": {
                  "@(2,value)": "&6.&5[&4].&3.value"
                }
              },
              "value": "&6.&5[&4].&3.value",
              "*": "&4.&3[&2].&1.&"
            },
            "*": "&3.&2[&1].&"
          }
        },
        "*": "&1.&"
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "component": {
        "parameters": {
          "*": {
            "parameter": {
              "name": {
                "@": "&5.&4[&3].&2.&1", // @ matches the value taken from one level up, eg. replicating "name"
                "var_name": {
                  "#new_val": "&6.&5[&4].&3.value"
                },
                "*": {
                  "@(2,value)": "&6.&5[&4].&3.value"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "*": "&" // the "else" case(the attributes other than "component")
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!
Is it a correct interpration to say that your additions (the '@' and the '*') cover the non matching cases and replicate the structure?

Comment: nice to help @Voxeldoodle , have a nice study!